# Grafana shift in time with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, timezone, grafana

I have a postgres table with timestamp. Postgres is set to CET. Grafana is also set to CET.

In the database I have timestamps up to eg. 2 p.m. What I see in Grafana is only data up to 1 p.m. If I change the timezone, the time axis is changed, but not all data are selected from data base, i.e. the data of last hour is always missing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic rule is to have data in the DB in the **UTC timezone**.
Grafana queries DB in the UTC timezone and then it will "move" UTC DB result into selected dashboard time zone automatically (usually it is a browser timezone, but timezone can be configured in the dashboard configuration).

Any non UTC timezone for data in DB means problem. Local timezone is also a problem because Daylight Saving Time. Did you think how your data will be saved when there is change CET <-> CEST ? You will have doubled data or missing data for one hour. So golden rule: data in the DB must be saved in the UTC timezone.

Comment: Will it work if I store the data in timestamptz with the right timezone? even if the DB is in CET?

Comment: @MichaelHecht yes, PostgreSQL stores the timestamptz in UTC value